# OpenSSL Certificate too long?

Tags: api, openssl, ssl-certificate

Good day as I mention above i generate a certificate which i found too long, i follow this tutorial on the net http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_facebook_integration.htm

and found his cert as a few strings, well mine is rather too different... a multiline (5 line) of random letters. Is it fine to have this?  im trying to implement facebook API to my android App. Thanks in advance, I appreciate any words from you guys thanks. I dunno i just feel that theres something wrong... cheers.

[image]

Comment: I might be missing something obvious... You're talking about someone else's cert and your cert is different. You don't provide the other's cert, and it looks like you exported your public key. What exactly is your problem and question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `openssl sha1 -binary` in the command. Therefore you got base64 certificate and not base64 of SHA1 of the certificate.